# GStreamer# equivalent for video overlay functions

Tags: c#, mono, gstreamer-sharp

I have a C#/Mono application for rendering video streams and, until recently, I've been using my own in-house developed InterOp bindings.

I'm now moving from that method to use those of GStreamer#, since that's likely to be much less maintenance effort, at least for me :-)

Since I need to bind independent video streams to a specific `DrawableArea` widgets, my method captured the GStreamer messages then checked them with the function `gst_is_video_overlay_prepare_window_handle_message(msg)`<sup>(a)</sup>.

If that returned true, I then responded with a call to `gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(xid)`, where `xid` was the handle for the widget obtained earlier with `gdk_x11_window_get_xid()`.

My problem is this: searching through the GStreamer# code, I cannot find an equivalent function for doing the binding so I was wondering how this is meant to be done.

Anyone have any advice or information to offer?

The source code for those two functions are in `gst-plugins-base-1.4.4/gst-libs/gst/video/videooverlay.c` so, in a pinch, I could dummy up my own functions to do the job (or just stick with our bindings for that one *little* bit) but it seems to me this would have been included in GStreamer# since rendering to specific widgets seems like a very handy facility.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Those GStreamer wags. They must replace their keyboards quite a bit with all that unnecessary typing :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out those functions *are* available, but in a separate library and sub-namespace to the baseline GStreamer stuff.

The getting of the Xid is still done with a self-made InterOp binding, to wit:

```
[DllImport("libgdk-3", EntryPoint = "gdk_x11_window_get_xid")]
private extern static IntPtr GdkX11WindowGetXid(IntPtr window);
```

You also have instance-level variables for the playbin, bus and X11 window ID:

```
private IntPtr windowXid;
private Gst.Element playBin;
private Gst.Bus bus;
```

Then, when instantiating the class, you capture the `Realized` signal and ensure that all messages on the GStreamer bus go to your callback function:

```
this.Realized += OnRealized;
playBin = Gst.ElementFactory.Make('playbin', 'playbin');
bus = playBin.Bus;
bus.AddSignalWatch();
bus.Message += MessageCallback;
```

In that realisation function, you save the Xid for later use (in an instance variable):

```
void OnRealized(object o, EventArgs args) {
    windowXid = GdkX11WindowGetXid(this.Window.Handle);
}
```

and, when asked by GStreamer, provide this handle in response to the request:

```
private void MessageCallback(object o, MessageArgs args) {
    Gst.Message msg = args.Message;
    if (! Gst.Video.Global.IsVideoOverlayPrepareWindowHandleMessage(msg))
        return;

    Gst.Element src = msg.Src as Gst.Element;
    if (src == null)
        return;

    Gst.Element overlay = null;
    if (src is Gst.Bin)
        overlay = ((Gst.Bin)src).GetByInterface

    Gst.Video.VideoOverlayAdapter = new Gst.Video.VideoOverlayAdapter(overlay.Handle);
    adapter.WindowHandle = windowXid;
}
```

Note that I've fully qualified all the GStreamer objects so it's absolutely clear where they can be found. The code would probably be a lot cleaner without them (and with using `var` for the variables) but I wanted to ensure all information was available.